# In django, when posting a new object via a form, how do you manually enter in its foreign keys?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

In my case, I have two models: a parent and a child.

On my post page, I have made it so that both the parent and multiple child class are posted into my database. The child classes have the parent as a foreign key.

How do I reference the foreign key in my child model?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the structure of your models

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, models.CASCADE)
```

In your view, you can reference the parent like so

```
def my_view(request):
    # ...
    parent = child.parent
```